# Why did Palpatine trust so many people with his plan for the Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, sith, the-clone-wars, darth-sidious

In canon, the Kaminoans are aware the Sith are in charge of the GAR cloning program. They are aware of the request for inhibitor chips in every single clone, and what these chips will be programmed to do. Enough of them know so that the Kaminoans deployed across the galaxy to support the GAR are aware and able to spot any risk of leaks to the plan on-site and attempt cover-ups ASAP.

In Legends, the clones themselves know what they are born to do, and are aware of the fate they themselves will hand to the Jedi at the end of the war.

Either way, that's millions of people who are aware of the Sith's identity, the existence and true purpose of the inhibitor chips and/or the true reason for the existence of Order 66.

Why is Palpatine so willing to let so many in on his plan? I know he may not have much of a choice if he wants to wipe out a whole Order of enemies, but even if he needs to let these people know, how is it that there doesn't seem to be any plans or contingencies to prevent or deal with potential leaks?

Comment: How do the Kaminoans know the Sith are in charge of the cloning program?? Sifo-Dyas ordered them (as far as they know at least), and he was a Jedi Master. Only Jango knows about Tyranus (which he admits to Obi-Wan rather late in the game); the *Darth* part Jango leaves out completely though. --- The inhibitor chip thing is covered up, and iirc it doesn't get out... at least not to millions, does it?

Comment: Do we know that Order 66 said "kill the Jedi" and not "[there's been a coup,] execute your commanding officer"?

Comment: Self-reply: [apparently, yes](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Contingency_Orders_for_the_Grand_Army_of_the_Republic:_Order_Initiation,_Orders_1_Through_150#), the order was specifically targetting Jedi. To be fair, only *traitorous* Jedi *officers*; Order 66 did *not* cover killing loyal Jedi officers, or any Jedi outside the command structure of the GAR. Removing traitorous officers (the assumption of the order) would not sound weird to a soldier at all, I suspect, and the additional order can be justified by Jedi being outside of the normal punitive system of the GAR.

Comment: Therefore, a Clone trooper/officer who truly believed that their CO *was* indeed loyal (contrary to the implied statement by SC Palpatine activating the order) would not have been bound to Order 66.

Answer (score 40):

Order 66 was never planned by anyone other than Palpatine. There were 150 contingency orders, including one to [arrest/kill the Supreme Chancellor](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Order_65).

I would assume that their inhibitor chip would activate at the moment any of these orders were given, in order to ensure full obedience. Therefore it wasn't "known" that any of these orders would need to be executed (including order 66), they were simply there as a failsafe.

It is likely that Palpatine asked the cloners to include all of these contingency plans in order to make sure that the single one he wanted (killing all of the Jedi) would not seem so suspicious when put in a list of a great many drastic orders. The Kaminoans would never have caught on that he planned to execute order 66 all along.

Comment: I think all the chips did was make the clones loyal to Palpatine. But if all it ensured was loyalty to the supreme chancellor, it might be that no-one questions it as he *is* the head of government and it needs them to be loyal to *someone*.

Comment: If only they were self-aware, they'd obviously be suspicious of an order numbered 66! But "Execute Order 104" doesn't have the same ring to it, even if it is more subtle.

Comment: @raumkrieger my assumption was that it was number 66 because it was round about the middle of the 150, so it's nestled less conspicuously in the middle of all the plans, but that was pure speculation. As a creative decision, 66 does sound much more ominous.

Comment: "Order 63, make a grilled cheese. Order 64, dispose of any bubble gum you may have on your person...Order 66, kill all the jedi. Order 67, silly shirt day - all troopers can wear a fun under shirt today..." Wait, what was that last one?

Comment: @BrianDHall I really hope that all the clones that defied Order 66 were just suffering from an off-by-one error, and they all started wearing silly shirts from that day onward.

Comment: @BrianDHall That's not too far off from [Robot Chicken's take on the first 65 Orders](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7CRatBZBaY).

Comment: @Thunderforge Thank you so much for sharing that, I hadn't seen that before! "Maybe I'll just email you a PDF for something..." Fantastic

Answer (score 2):

**Kaminoans do not know that Order 66 and whole Clone army was planned and ordered by Sith**

In *Clone Wars* [S06E03](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Conspiracy) Kaminoans are taking orders from Tyranus, in order to safeguard Protocol 66 (Order 66) and secret of inhibitor chips from Jedi. But they do not know full truth - they do not know that Tyranus is actually Darth Tyranus i.e. Count Dooku . They only know him as a man who ordered (and presumably payed for) Clone Army. It appears that they believe his explanation that Protocol 66 serves to protect Republic from Jedi takeover.

Other contingency orders are now part of Legends, they contradict Canon explanation that inhibitor chips, when activated, take complete control of clone behavior forcing them to kill any Jedi they could find. Also in Canon clones certainly do not know what is their true purpose. In fact, **in Canon only two person that certainly know about Sith plan for Order 66 are Palaptine and Dooku**, and Palpatine arranged Dooku to be killed.

Comment: Tarkin and Palpatine were already close at thus point in time, any reason to suspectthat he was in the loop?

Comment: @psubsee2003 Tarkin was never fully certain Palpatine is a Sith. He had his private thoughts about it, but never full confirmation. From the novel "Tarkin" there is no reason to believe that he was as close to Palpatine as Vader, and even Vader never learned total extent of conspiracy involving Order 66.